# __metaclass__ adding invalid attribute to class created?

Tags: python, attributes, metaclass

**metaclass** adding invalid attribute to class?

Here is my code:

```
def __metaclass__(clsname, bases, dct):
    dct["key1"] = "value1"
    dct["invalid identifier"] = "value2"
    return type(clsname, bases, dct)


class Cls():
    pass



for name in dir(Cls):
    if not name.startswith("_"):
        print name
```

when I run it,  I got:

```
>>> 
invalid identifier
key1
>>>
```

Is is possible to access the `invalid identifier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still access that identifier with `getattr()`:

```
getattr(Cls, 'invalid identifier')
```

or directly on the class `__dict__` mapping:

```
Cls.__dict__['invalid identifier']
```

You just cannot use direct attribute access as it is indeed not a valid identifier.